# Sessions not working in Safari

Tags: php, google-chrome, session, safari

When I define a variable with `$_SESSION['variable'] = "Some random text";`
it works perfectly in Google Chrome. When I do it on Safari, it does not store the variable. I am using `session_start();`

Comment: check your  Safari is accepting cookies

Comment: @nogad How do I do that?

Comment: [Google > Safari Cookie Settings](https://www.google.com/#q=safari+cookie+settings) literally has a step-by-step guide at the top.

Comment: @nogad I checked my cookies, and Safari is accepting cookies

Comment: Cleaned up the grammer slightly in the question. If you can please include more details in regards to your code. Perhaps posting a little bit more of the session handling parts as well as, is this using HTTPS for form submission? If so that might be the issue but either way we need more info to be able to help.